# Element-api - filter Draft entries by the draft author (not original author)

Tags: plugin-elementapi, author, draft

I have a remote app that enables preview based on your editor craft account. I want to retrieve draft entries that they are working on, but i cant find a way to do this. 'authorId' seems to always be the original author of the entry, rather than the draft.

Here is the important bit of my code ->

```
$user = Craft::$app->users->getUserByUsernameOrEmail($userp);

           return [
          'elementType' => Entry::class,
          'paginate' => false,
          'pretty' => true,
          'criteria' => ['draftId' => $entryId, 'section' => 'cashwrap', 'drafts' => true, 'orderBy'   => 'dateUpdated desc', 'authorId' => $user->id, 'limit' => 10 ],
```

I cant find any ref for retrieving, or filtering by the draft author id? The above will only show drafts for original author id not draft author.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have found the answer after digging in Element docs... looks like this works! in criteria

```
'draftCreator' => $user->id
```